# Hide deis application using dns, heroku style

Tags: heroku, dns, deis

I've got a deis cluster correctly setup. Everything is working fine, deploys, scales, etc. It is set at a domain that I will call mydeiscluster.com

Now it has come to the part where I need to hide the application foo, which is accessed by foo.mydeiscluster.com behind using my other domain DNS.
I want that dashboard.myotherdomain.com masks foo.mydeiscluster.com, just like it would happend using heroku.

Has anyone done that?

Just setting the CNAME record on myotherdomain.com does not work, I need some config on deis but I was not able to find it using the docs.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a [Custom Domain](http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/using_deis/config-application/#custom-domains), which adds support for alternate CNAMEs to your existing app.  You can set this with:

```
deis domains:add dashboard.myotherdomain.com -a foo
```

This will ensure traffic addressed to `dashboard.myotherdomain.com` is routed to the `foo` application.  Note you must configure DNS to point to the Deis router mesh.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it. Thank you so much!